# Bad input shape error on sklearn digit datasets

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
import sklearn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm

digits = datasets.load_digits()

clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.01,C= 100)

x = digits.data[:-10]
y = digits.data[:-10]

clf.fit(x,y)

print ("prediction:",clf.predict(digits.data[-1]))

plt.imshow(digits.image[-1],cmap = plt.cm.gray_r, interpolation ="nearest")
plt.show
```

I get error as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 14, in <module>
ValueError: bad input shape (1787, 64)
```

I'm unsure what and how the shape of the array should be?!!

Could Someone help here! thanks

Comment: It should be `y = digits.data[-10:]`.

Comment: @COLDSPEED thanks for your comment, I changed it to the way you said and still throws up error as

  File "python", line 15, in <module>
ValueError: bad input shape (10, 64)

Comment: Whatever errors you have should be edited into your post. Comments aren't the best place to debug broken code. By the way, I'd recommend trying to figure out what your data and your labels are, and slicing accordingly. I certainly don't know, because it isn't my data and I won't ssh into your system to find out.

Comment: Load features to `x` and labels to `y`. Second line should be `y = digits.target[:-10]`

Comment: Why was my answer down-voted when I gave a right answer to the OP?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Arya McCarthy's suggestion on using `digits.target` as `y` was right. Hence, declaring `digits.data` as feature variables `x` and `digits.target` as target variables `y` is correct. Kindly try out your code I revised as follows:

```
import sklearn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import svm

digits = datasets.load_digits()

clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.01,C= 100)

x = digits.data
y = digits.target

clf.fit(x,y)
print ("prediction:",clf.predict(digits.data[-1].reshape(1, -1)))
plt.imshow(digits.images[-1],cmap = plt.cm.gray_r, interpolation ="nearest")
plt.show()
```

The following was the result of my run of the code

[image]

Comment: Why was my answer down-voted when I gave a right answer to the OP?

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to use `digits.target` as `y`, not `digits.data`. The SVM only accepts a 1D prediction variable, which hints that you're passing the wrong value to it. `target` is the value (0..9) that the 8x8 image in `x` portrays.